# Sequencing dependencies of multiple Gradle plugin tasks

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

**Please note:** Although I specifically mention two Gradle plugins here, this is 100% a question about understanding task dependencies in Gradle, and does *not* require any knowledge of the individual plugins (I think)!

---

I have a project that will use two Gradle plugins:

- The [Gradle Shadow plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/), which will produce a self-contained "fat jar" (basically a large jar with all my classes plus the classes of all my transitive dependencies, which then allows me to just run `java -jar myapp.jar` without having to manage the jar's external classpath, etc.). This will produce a fat jar at `build/libs/myapp.jar`; and
- The [Gradle Launch4J plugin](https://github.com/TheBoegl/gradle-launch4j), which uses Launch4J under the hood to convert a jar into a native executable (EXE, etc.). **Obviously the fat jar has to be created prior to the Launch4J tasks run, otherwise they'll have nothing to wrap inside of an EXE!**

Here's my `build.gradle`:

```
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.transformers.ServiceFileTransformer

plugins {
    id 'groovy'
    id 'application'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '1.2.3'
    id 'edu.sc.seis.launch4j' version '2.3.0'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

group = 'hotmeatballsoup'
mainClassName = 'com.me.myapp.Driver'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile(
        'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.7'
        ,'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.24'
        ,'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.24'
    )
}

manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Class': mainClassName
}
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': mainClassName
    }
    baseName = 'zimbus'
}

shadowJar {
    transform(ServiceFileTransformer) {
        exclude 'META-INF/*.DSA'
        exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA'
        exclude 'LICENSE*'
    }
    transform(com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.transformers.AppendingTransformer) {
        resource = 'reference.conf'
    }
    classifier = ''
}

publishing {
    publications {
        shadow(MavenPublication) {
            from components.shadow
            artifactId = 'zimbus'
        }
    }
}

launch4j {
    outfile = 'zimbus.exe'
    mainClassName = 'com.me.myapp.Driver'
    icon = 'zimbus.ico'
    jar = 'build/libs/gradle-launch4j-example.jar'
}
```

At the command-line I run:

```
./gradlew clean build shadowJar createAllExecutables
```

The *intention* here is that I want the fat jar created first (invoked when `shadowJar` runs) and *then* for Launch4J to kick in (which is invoked when `createAllExecutables` runs). But when I run this I get the following exception:

```
:createExe FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':createExe'.
> Launch4J finished with non-zero exit value 1
  launch4j: Application jar doesn't exist.
```

I'm pretty sure the `createAllExecutables` task is firing *before* the `shadowJar` task, and thus having nothing (no fat jar) to bundle up inside an EXE.

Can someone confirm my suspicion and help me define the `dependsOn` declaration that will order my tasks correctly? Or if the tasks *are* executing in the correct order, maybe offer any ideas as to what is causing the error?

Comment: It seems that you just need to add `createAllExecutables.dependsOn shadowJar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you write

> createAllExecutables.dependsOn shadowJar

you'll define the dependency between createAllExecutables task and shadowJar, which means every time Gradle decide to invoke `createAllExecutables` (e.g. because you pass that to the command line, or other task will depend on it) `shadowJar` will also be added to the task graph. So in that case when you invoke `gradle createAllExecutables` the `shadowJar` will be also executed.

But you can also write

> createAllExecutables.mustRunAfter shadowJar

In that case, you won't introduce any dependency relation between tasks, but you will instrument Gradle about anticipated order for those two tasks. In that case, once you invoke `gradle createAllExecutables` the `shadowJar` won't be executed.

I think the `dependsOn` relation is more applicable in your case, since in order to create executables you need to have fat jar already, so it's a *depend* on relation, not *must run after*.